# Standalone convert doesn't work

Tags: standalone, png, convert

I'm using TexMaker and want to make a PNG file from a TikZ figure.
When using the `preview` option in `standalone` class, I get a beautiful PDF, but when switching to `convert` I get a massage that "Process started" but it doesn't compile. (I've installed the windows version of ImageMagick).

Comment: you could try [pdf2png.com](https://pdf2png.com)

Comment: What exactly is stated in the generated log file? Not what TeXMaker reads from the log. It might be an idea to manually compile this `.tex` file using (I assume) `pdflatex file.tex` from the command line. Some editors have a tendency to not show all the errors/messages. My guess is a missing option to enable `pdflatex` to run external programmes.

Comment: I did enable `pdflatex -shell-escape`. My guess that it's some driver for the conversion itself, but I have no idea where to look...

Comment: Then list what the log says, can it even find `convert` or whatever command from Imagemagick it is using

Comment: What compiler are you using? For example, LuaLaTeX needs an additional command to make hell escape work.

Answer (score 3):

One problem with the `convert` option under MS Windows is that the `convert` shell command is for FAT32 to NTFS conversion. The ImageMagick `convert.exe` might be taken or not. For safety `standalone` awaits the convert tool be named `imgconvert.exe`. Either change the `standalone` options or copy-rename the `convert.exe` file in the ImageMagick folder to `imgconvert.exe`.

If this doesn't work out, please post some example code, your compiler call and the log file.

Comment: In the meantime `convert.exe` got renamed to `magick.exe` by ImageMagick. I will update the package accordantly.

Comment: In the installation folder of ImageMagick there are both `convert.exe` and `magick.exe`, so which one should be renamed according to your comment?

Comment: @Diaa: Originally there was just a `convert.exe`. Newer version of Image Magick use `magick.exe` but allow to install the old file as well. I still have to update the package to reflect this.